# Return from Android Gallery in jUnit?

Tags: android, android-activity, junit, gallery, robotium

I have an application in which if you click a button, it opens the Android Gallery application. The user can then select an image for my application. The thing is, if I click that button in JUnit, it opens up the Gallery and then just sits there. I have to manually choose a picture. I just want to be able to open the Gallery and then go back or if possible select an image.

I tried several options such as -

```
sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
Robotiums goBack(), goBackToActivity(), sendKey() functions
Robotiums clickOnScreen() function to click and select an image
```

but none of these seem to work. So what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. You can't do this, as the Android Gallery is another application running in its own sandbox which you cannot reach from your testing code.

However, I came up with the following solution. You can build your own dummy application that provides an Intent filter for opening images. In this application you simply return the intent with an ok.

Now you only have to select your application as the default application when first opening your image from your test application. Afterwards, everything should work automatically.

Once you're done with testing, you can reset the default intent filter in your Android device's settings.

The code for my solution can be found in this discussion: [How to provide content for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933984/how-to-provide-content-for-intent-action-get-content/11940519#11940519)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simulate response returned from gallery.
The code snippet below do all the work.

```
final Intent data = new Intent();
data.setData(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/458")); // put here URI that you want select in gallery
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getActivity().onActivityResult(3333,-1, data);
        synchronized(this) {
            this.notify();
        }
    }
};
synchronized(runnable) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
    runnable.wait();
}
```

This method has two drawbacks:

1. onActivityResult method of your activity should be public which brakes encapsulation.
2. Test will not actually click button which opens gallery and onClick handler won't be executed.

But the benefit of such approach is that you don't need to build mock application and change any defaults in android settings.